# Return empty if property doesn't exist in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, func

I have one predicate that is searching from a collection,i want to check if my class property is not in the object then i want to return empty i.e "" not null.

```
 Func<IModel, string> predicateField03 = s => s.GetType().GetProperty("Field03") != null && s.Field03.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) ? s.Field03.ToLower() : string.Empty;
```

Above query returns in object as **Field03=null** but i want result like **Field03=""**
Where i am doing wrong please correct.

Comment: Show us how you are calling that code.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem there is that you're checking if an IModel has certain property and then you're trying to access that property as if it were part of IModel, so it doesn't make sense to me.

You could try to get the value using reflection as well:

```
public class Program
{
    public interface IModel {}

    public class Model1 : IModel{}
    public class Model2 : IModel {
        public string Field03 {get;set;}
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<IModel, string> predicateField03 = s => s.GetType().GetProperty("Field03") != null && s.GetType().GetProperty("Field03").GetValue(s).ToString().ToLower().Contains("33") ? 
            s.GetType().GetProperty("Field03").GetValue(s).ToString() : string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine(predicateField03(new Model1()));
        Console.WriteLine(predicateField03(new Model2(){Field03 = "333"}));

    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KGjPA